# Write a grid to a File

Tags: c++

I am writing code to read in a set of numbers and then display them in a 4x4 grid on screen, the program will then determine if it is a magic square.  My question is how can I get the user to input the numbers into a file that is shown in the readData method so that when that method is called it will display the users grid.

Also where does the file data.txt get stored?

thanks

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
using namespace std;
const int dimension = 4;   // dimension for the array
typedef int Sq[dimension] [dimension];  // declare vector for type names

void ReadData(Sq square ) // read data from file
{  ifstream inFile;
  char fileName[13] = "data.txt";
  inFile.open (fileName);  // open file for reading                
  for (int r = 0; r < dimension; r++)   // row loop
      for ( int c = 0; c < dimension; c++)  // column loop
            inFile >> square[r][c]; // read data into matrix
      inFile.close( ); // close the file                
}

void Display ( const Sq square ) // display matrix
{ cout << " Magic Square Program " << endl << endl;
 for (int r = 0; r < dimension; r++)
   { for ( int c = 0; c < dimension; c++)
        { cout.width(6);  //set output width to 6 characters
           cout << square[r][c] << "\t ";  // display numbers
            }
       cout << endl;
    }    
 }
bool magicSquare( Sq square)  // add rows, columns, and diagonals
{ int firstSum = 0, sum;
  bool magic = true;
  for (int r = 0; r < dimension; r++) // add 1st column for a comparison
      firstSum += square[r][1]; 
   for (int r = 1; r < dimension; r++) // row loop first when adding rows
      { sum = 0;
         for ( int c = 0; c < dimension; c++)
             sum += square[r][c];  // add row
         if ( sum != firstSum)  // check for magic failure
              return (false);  // not magic
       }

     for ( int c = 0; c < dimension; c++)   // column loop first when adding columns
       { sum = 0;
          for (int r = 0; r < dimension; r++)
              sum += square[r][c];   // add columns
              if ( sum != firstSum)  // check for magic failure
               return (false);  // not magic
        }
     sum = 0;
     for (int r = 0; r < dimension; r++)  
          sum += square[r][r];   // add front diagonal
        if ( sum != firstSum)  // check for magic failure
           return (false);  // not magic
      sum = 0;
      for (int r = 0; r < dimension; r++)  
          sum += square[r][dimension - r - 1];   // add back diagonal
         if ( sum != firstSum)  // check for magic failure
          return (false);  // not magic
      else
          return (true);
      }  // end magicSquare function

int main( )
{
  Sq square;
 ReadData( square);  // read data from file
 Display ( square);  // display matrix
 if ( magicSquare(square) )   // check for magic property
    cout << "\n This Square is Magic \n " << endl;
 else
    cout << "\n This Square is Not Magic \n " << endl;
 system("Pause");
 return(0);
 }
```

Comment: Too much code, my eyes hurt. Can you narrow it down a bit?

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to make the program take the filename as a command-line argument. Main should really look like this, where `argc` is the number of arguments, and `argv[]` is and array of char pointers to them (`argv[0]` is always the name of the executable). See [What does int argc, char *argv[] mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3024197/what-does-int-argc-char-argv-mean)

```
int main(int argc, char * argv[])
```

So then, you do

```
if (argc == 2)
{
   ReadData(square, argv[1]);
   ...
}
else
  ...
```

And ReadData would look like this:-

```
void ReadData(Sq &square, const std::string &filename) // read data from file
{
  ifstream inFile;
  inFile.open (filename);  // open file for reading
```

NOTE! you need to take square as a *reference* parameter (`&square`) otherwise your input data just gets ignored.

Answer (score 0):

> My question is how can I get the user to input the numbers into a file that is shown in the readData method?

Ask politely? Since it's a file on the disk, user has to fill it *before* the program starts. You could use appropriate `ifstream` flag to **not** create the file if it doesn't exist, and display an error message instead, terminating the program afterwards.

> Also where does the file data.txt get stored?

In the current execution path of the binary. This may or may not be the folder where the binary is located.

As a side note, as you are using C++, `std::array<>` might be a better fit than C-style arrays.